# Accessing variable of a method in superclass

Tags: java, class, variables

I have a basic code with an Animal class and a Dog and a Cat subclass. I have a speak method. The speak method receives a string, and returns a string in cat and dog "language". If a character's ascii code is even, it returns "uff", if not, "vau". When I override the method, I want to set oddSound and evenSound from the Dog class, but I can't find a proper way to do this.
This code is from the Animal class:

```
public String speak(String what){
    String speakableString = new String();
    String oddSound = new String();
    String evenSound = new String();

    for (int i = 0; i < what.length(); i++) {
        if((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 1){ 
            speakableString.concat(oddSound); 
        }else if ((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 0){
            speakableString.concat(evenSound);
        }
    }

    speakableString = speakableString.substring(0, speakableString.length()-1);
    return speakableString;
}
```

This code is from the Dog class:

```
public String speak(String what){
    //set oddSound = "vau"
    //set evenSound = "uff"
    return super.speak(what);
}
```

Comment: `.concat()` doesn't change anything.

Comment: If the problem persists after fixing `.concat()` statement, please post the relevant code for inheritance.

Comment: Sounds like `oddSound` and `evenSound` shouldn't be local variables to the method but rather properties on the `Dog` or `Cat` classes.

Comment: This is not an error solving question. I will try to make this more clear by editing the question.

Comment: @mattm That is actually a good idea. Could you give a detailed explanation?

Comment: You could add fields "oddsound" and "evensound" to the animal class, when you are creating a Dog or a Cat, you can set these fields specificly to the animal! And in the speak method you are checking the characters, and returning either the odd or even property of the animal!

Comment: @SLaks I edited the code, I think now it is more clear what the concat method does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep them as data members, and set them in the respective constructors:

```
public class Animal {
    private String oddSound;
    private String evenSound;

    protected Animal (String oddSound, String evenSound) {
        this.oddSound = oddSound;
        this.evenSound = evenSound;
    }

    public String speak(String what){
        String speakableString = new String();

        for (int i = 0; i < what.length(); i++) {
            if((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 1){ 
                speakableString = speakableString.concat(oddSound); 
            }else if ((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 0){
                speakableString = speakableString.concat(evenSound);
            }
        }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        super ("uff", "vau");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `Animal` class, have two protected fields,

```
protected String oddSound;
protected String evenSound;
```

Then, in the `Dog` and `Cat` classes, you can set these fields:

```
oddSound = "woof";
evenSound = "woofwoof"
```

Then, in the `speak()` method, you can simply use `this.oddSound` and `this.evenSound`

Comment: And how can I access the private variable of `Cat` from `Animal`?

Comment: Actually, this answers my question completely, but the other answer was a little "nicer".

Answer (score 0):

The Animal class should declare your speak method, since that is common to both the Dog and Cat classes.

```
public class Animal {
    String oddSound;
    String evenSound;

    public Animal(String oddSound, String evenSound) {
        this.oddSound = oddSound;
        this.evenSound = evenSound;
    }

    public String speak(String what){
        String speakableString = new String();

        for (int i = 0; i < what.length(); i++) {
            if((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 1){ 
                speakableString = speakableString.concat(oddSound); 
            }else if ((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 0){
                speakableString = speakableString.concat(evenSound);
            }
        }

    speakableString = speakableString.substring(0, speakableString.length()-1);
    return speakableString;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that the string.concat method creates a *new* object, it does not modify the instance on which it's called. See [String API Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String))

Your Dog and Cat classes should define or override methods only as needed. It seems all you're doing in their speak method is calling the super method implementation. You can get rid of that completely.

If you want to extend the Animal class to provide new methods or implementations, do it like this:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog() {
        // This calls the super constructor, which sets the oddSound and evenSound fields
        super("vau", "uff");
    }

    // This section does nothing.
    // A method implementation which only calls its super implementation is ineffective.
    // If you were to provide a new implementation, this is where it would be.
    //public String speak(String what) {
    //  super.speak(what);  
    //}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could break up your speak implementation in to two parts to allow you to pass in the Strings that you want to use for `oddSound` and `evenSound`.

```
public String speak(String what){
    return getSpeakableString(what, new String(), new String());
}
protected String getSpeakableString(String what, String oddSound, String evenSound){
    //this is just copied from what you had in your question, it likely doesn't do what you actually want.
    String speakableString = new String();
    for (int i = 0; i < what.length(); i++) {
        if((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 1){ 
            speakableString.concat(oddSound); 
        }else if ((((int) what.charAt(i)) & 1) == 0){
            speakableString.concat(evenSound);
        }
    }
    speakableString = speakableString.substring(0, speakableString.length()-1);
    return speakableString;
}

//in subclass
@Override
public String speak(String what){
    return getSpeakableString(what, "vau", "uff");
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I did the first time I got the exercise. But my teacher said this is not the best way, and I should find a new way to do this.

Comment: Passing them in probably isn't the best idea considering this is a method and we can simply set a field or property.